# AR(2) process covariance stationarity - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

Say I specify an AR(2) process as $X_t = 0.5 + 0.7X_{t-1} + 0.4X_{t-2} + e_t$.  I would not expect this process to be covariance stationary.  Indeed, if I project this series stochastically, it grows very quickly.

The characteristic polynomial is, I think, $0.5 - 0.7z - 0.4z^2=0$.  The roots of this equation are, I think, $-2.29$ and $0.54$.  These roots lie outside the unit circle.  Which suggests that the process is covariance stationary.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First, the characteristic polynomial is $1-0.7z-0.4z^2$, the coefficient $0.5$ being irrelevant. Second, the stability condition (with your convention for the characteristic polynomial) is that **every** root lies outside the unit disk. This condition fails for the characteristic polynomial above (ironically, it also fails for the wrong version you manipulated in your question).

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't have literature here.

However, I have the following in my mind: the sum of the coefficients equals $1.1 \geq 1,$ such that your time-series doesn't necessarily has to be stationary. I could imagine that there's an implication if the sum is greater 1 (no stationary solution) and that there's an implication if the sum is equal 1 (Integrated AR(2)-model.)

Excuse my vague answer.